# jQuery slideToggle moves navigation elements out of place

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Hi I trying to create a drop down menu using jQuery, I'm using the `slideToggle` function in order to close the previous menu on the next click. However when I click a navigation element the other elements seem to drop about `20px`.

I'm not 100% sure as to why this is occurring, would appreciate if somebody could tell me where I've gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

My code is below or view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCaQ2/)

js/js.js

```
$('.nav_parent h5').click(function () {
  $(this).next('.nav_child').slideToggle();
   $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="header_nav">
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Reports</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Download CSV</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Build</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Build new site</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Subscriptions</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">E-Briefings</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_parent">
            <h5>Media Store</h5>

            <ul class="nav_child">
                <li><a href="#" class="mnavlink">Image Store</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css/style.css

```
.nav_parent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:24%;
    background:#FCCC5F;
}
.nav_parent h5:hover {
    background:#FCE49D;
}
.nav_child {
    display:none;
}
.nav_child li {
    line-height:30px;
}
.nav_child li:hover {
    background:#FCE49D;
}
```

Comment: Just add `float: left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in your css. Change to:

```
.nav_parent {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    width:24%;  
    background:#FCCC5F;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uCaQ2/
fiddle